# Elixir mixins used for validation callbacks

Tags: elixir

I've read other SO answers around this subject but I specifically wanted to focus on Elixir's own [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html) that talks about mixins and DSLs.

In their example, they say that these are three options:

```
# 1. data structures
import Validator
validate user, name: [length: 1..100],
               email: [matches: ~r/@/]

# 2. functions
import Validator
user
|> validate_length(:name, 1..100)
|> validate_matches(:email, ~r/@/)

# 3. macros + modules
defmodule MyValidator do
  use Validator
  validate_length :name, 1..100
  validate_matches :email, ~r/@/
end

MyValidator.validate(user)
```

Of course, the examples aren't complete.  So I thought I'd try to complete style #3 to better understand some of the libraries I'm using that uses some of these styles (not necessarily style #3).

There's kind of a gotcha with trying to do this in a `test.exs` file because *the struct was not yet defined or the struct is being accessed in the same context that defines it* but getting around that with a Main module leads me to something like this:

```
defmodule Validator do

  defmacro __using__(_params) do
    quote do
      def validate_length(field, length_rules) do
        String.length(field) >= length_rules.first and String.length(field) <= length_rules.last
      end
    end
  end

end

defmodule MyValidator do
  use Validator
  validate_length :name, 1..10
end

defmodule User do
  @enforce_keys [:name]
  defstruct [:name]
end

defmodule Main do
  def run do
    user = %User{name: "Joe"}
    MyValidator.validate(user)
  end
end

Main.run
# undefined function validate_length/2
```

I wouldn't expect this to work because I don't understand the connection between `MyValidator` and the "callbacks" for what validate means.  Am I supposed to look up (metaprogram) what validations have been used?  Am I supposed to implement `_params` to see what callbacks are to be used in the future?

Even so, the error is `undefined function validate_length/2` because there's no "wiring" between the two.  Of course if I change the main to be something like:

```
defmodule MyValidator do
  use Validator
end

def run do
  user = %User{name: "Joe"}
  MyValidator.validate_length(user.name, 1..10)
```

Then of course that works but that's not doing a callback, that's just a mixin.

So how can you finish up the Elixir example #3 to act like a Mixin that could have many validators, many callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with strict disunion of two contexts: *compilation time* context vs *runtime* context.

To do this, one might start with the following example:

```rb
defmodule Foo do
  IO.puts "Compilation"

  def bar(), do: IO.puts "Runtime"
end
```

When *Elixir* compiles this, it prints the former. When *you* call `Foo.bar/0`, you’ll get the latter printed.

---

Now to macros. Macros are *compilation time* beasts. During the compilation stage, *Elixir* takes AST that the macro returns, and explicitly injects it into the place where the macro was called from. Consider the following example.

```rb
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro bar() do
    IO.puts "Compilation"
    quote do: IO.puts "Runtime"
  end

  def baz(), do: bar()
end
```

Try to compile it and then call `Foo.baz/0`. The thing is, *Elixir* macro language is *Elixir* and compiler is fine with executing code while traversing macros to AST. That’s why you get `"Compilation"` string printed only once. After compilation passed, the former `IO.puts/2` call *does not exist anymore*.

---

Now your example. In the first place don’t try to put the code that is expected to be compiled in `*.exs`. `s` stands for *script* and these files are *not compiled* during normal compilation stage by default. There are many reasons for that, but they are definitely out of scope here. So, put the code into separate files with `*.ex` extension.

Important: **you want the `validate/1` function to be available in *compilation time*.**

So, `use Validator` should a) inject the code for this function and b) import it into current context during compilation time. For it to be available during compilation stage, it should reside in a *different module* because this module must be already compiled by a time of injection. *Elixir* is not a scripting language and it cannot run not compiled code.

The summing up.

```rb
defmodule Validator do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      # you need this module IMPORTED
      import Validator
    end
  end
  # you need this function COMPILED
  def validate(foo) do
    if foo > 42,
      do: raise(ArgumentError, "FOO"),
      else: IO.puts("OK")
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use Validator

  validate 0    # prints out "OK"
  validate 100  # raises _during compilation_
end
```

---

For more sophisticated checks `validate` function might inject runtime AST.